# Patches to statically link gcc-8.2.0 against musl

Tags: gcc, patch

I want to build a cross-compiler toolchain with gcc-8.2.0 statically linked to musl. I am using [musl-cross-make](https://github.com/richfelker/musl-cross-make). It is patching all previous gcc versions, so I expect gcc-8.2.0 to need some fixes too.

It can be done: [here is a proof](https://skarnet.org/toolchains/).

Where can I find patches to statically link gcc-8.2.0 against musl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One source of patches are the toolchains mantained by Zach van Rijn on [enter link description here](https://git.zv.io/toolchains/musl-cross-make).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check in the Alpine source tree:

https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/main/gcc?h=master

They use MUSL based gcc 8.2.0 for release 3.9.0